# How do I append one element to a list as efficiently as possible

Tags: list, performance, functional-programming, clojure

At the end of [*CLOJURE for the BRAVE and TRUE*](https://www.braveclojure.com/core-functions-in-depth/)'s Chapter 4 there's an exercise: make an `append` function that appends a new entry to a list.

What's the most efficient way to do so?

From what I understand of datatypes in general, if `conj` prepends elements to a list, that simply means that consistently appending to a list is either silly or the choice of using a list type was silly.

Anyway, the solution I've written is this

```clj
(defn append
  [lst item]
  (into '() (conj (into '() lst) item)))
```

Well, that's actually the same as

```clj
(defn append
  [lst item]
  (reverse (conj (reverse lst) item)))
```

I believe, so probably is costly because I reverse the list twice?

Another solution I could think of is

```clj
(defn append
  [lst item]
  (apply list (conj (apply vector lst) item)))
```

But they all seem to traverse the sequence of values twice, so I don't see why any one should be better than another.

Is there *the* proper way to accomplish the task?

Comment: `(apply list (concat lst [item]))` will traverse only once. But I can't say whether it's more efficient or not - you'd have to profile it with different input sizes. It might easily be the case that one solution is better where the number of items is small but a different one is better for large inputs.

Answer (score 0):

There is a reason, why `conj` adds a new item at the start of the list and not at its end. Because you have to traverse the list to add something at its end. This is not very efficient. And it is because of the nature of a linked list. That's why in lisp you `cons` new items onto a list and at the very end `reverse` it. This way, you traverse the list just once while building it.

In Clojure, if you want to add to a list at the end, it is more idiomatic not to use a list but instead the vector type. On a vector, `conj` adds right to the end.

But let's say, you want to traverse a list once and add to the end.

That is actually:

```
(defn my-append [lst item] (concat lst (list item)))

(my-append '(1 2 3) 4)
;; (1 2 3 4)
```

but as I said, if you want to add repeatedly at the end, don't use a list, but a vector and `conj` to the end.

```
;; more idiomatic clojure in thisst to add something at its end. This is not very efficient. And it is because of the nature of a linked list. Tha case

(def v [1 2 3])

(conj v 4) ;; [1 2 3 4] ;; unbeatable in efficience, because no traversal!

;; and convert to a list
;; e.g.
(def l (conj v 4))
(seq l)    ;; (1 2 3 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

to avoid the double traversal, you could use the classic recursive approach. Something like this:

```
(defn append [lst item]
  (loop [res [] lst lst]
    (if (seq lst)
      (recur (conj res (first lst))
             (rest lst))
      (seq (conj res item)))))
```

so, it just rebuilds the list from scratch.
To make it's performance better in clojure, you can optimize it with transient collection:

```
(defn append' [lst item]
  (loop [res (transient []) lst lst]
    (if (seq lst)
      (recur (conj! res (first lst))
             (rest lst))
      (seq (persistent! (conj! res item))))))
```

but yes, as another answer proposes, you should carefully pick the proper data structure for every specific task, so in practice you would want to use vector.

As of `concat` variant, it comes for free (since it is lazy), but it has this known pitfall, which is stack overflow on applying a lot of stacked lazy functions:

```
user> (defn append-concat [lst item]
        (concat lst [item]))

user> (reduce append-concat () (range 1000000))
;; Error printing return value (StackOverflowError) at clojure.lang.LazySeq/sval (LazySeq.java:42).
```